# Nginx services fails for cross-domain requests if the service returns error

Tags: nginx, cors

I am making a cross domain request in my web app.

I have set the CORS headers on Nginx. Everything is working fine except when the service returns an error like 404, 400, 500 etc, instead of receiving the error code, the service is failing with an error saying that the `Origin *********** is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/431274/nginx-services-fails-for-cross-domain-requests-if-the-service-returns-error):

Unfortunately add_header won't work with status codes other than 200, 204, 301, 302 or 304. You can find this in the documentation here.

You may be able to use this plugin to do what you want:

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule

Answer (score 6):

As of v1.7.5 of nginx, you can add "always" to the end of the add_header line to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure? Is there documentation that states this? I am using nginx/1.8.0 and I don't get the CORS headers returned on 401 or 403 (which is what I want).

Comment: Answering way too late. From http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

"If the always parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code."